# Angular directive to append or delete a input element with unique id based on button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular and am trying to do this the Angular Way. I have a list with several `<li>` elements created using ng-repeat. In each `<li>` I have a button that increments a counter and one that decrements the counter and initially one `<input type=text>`. I want to append or remove a duplicate `<input type=text>` with a unique id corresponding to whether the increment or decrement button is clicked.

Here is the markup for the portion of my page template I'm working with

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item" ng-repeat="resource in resources">
    <div class="resource-desc">{{resource.description}}</div>
      <img ng-src="{{resource.thumb}}">
      <div class="incrementer" ng-controller="CounterCtrl">
      <button id='{{$index}}' class="count-btn ion-arrow-up-b"  ng-click="increment()" ng-init="count=0">
        <span class="ion-plus-round"></span>
      </button>
      <div id='{{$index}}'class="count-btn count">{{count}}</div>
      <button id='{{$index}}' class="ion-arrow-down-b"  ng-click="decrement()">
        <span class="ion-minus-round"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id='{{$index}}' class="multi-name-input">
      <div class="input_wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="{{$index}}resource" required>
        <label for="{{$index}}resource">Enter a Name to Display(ie Bay 1)</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And my Counter controller

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myapp.controllers', ['ionic', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('CounterCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.decrement = function() {
    $scope.count = $scope.count - 1;
    if ($scope.count < 0){
      $scope.count = 0;
    }
  };
  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
  };
})
```

The input markup for the partial I want appended

```
<div class="input_wrapper">
    <input id='{{$index}}' type="text" name="resource{{$index}}" required>
    <label for="resource{{$index}}">Enter a Name to Display</label>
</div>
```

I think my directive should look something like this

```
.directive('bw-input-append',function($compile){
    return {
        templateUrl: '../../templates/partials/text_input.html',
        transclude: true
        link: function(scope, element){
                  element.click(function(){
                    element.parent().find('.multi-name-input').append($compile(template)(scope));
                        });
                    }
    };
});
```

But I'm really not sure if that's right at all or what options I might need or want in the directive.

Comment: in angular you would normally add items to data array or remove from array. In your case `ng-click` would be used, and a conroller function would do the adding/removing

Comment: But I thought DOM manipulation was not suppose to happen except through directives and never through your controllers?

Comment: right, but my point is letting the data model do the DOM manipulation. Can you create a simple demo with some data in plunker?

Comment: I have modified two JSFiddles that I found. Each does a piece of what I'm trying to achieve. The first [http://jsfiddle.net/MfHa6/442/] uses ng-include so it compiles my template. But it is being initiated through a drop-down using ng-options. The second [http://jsfiddle.net/M45G3/31/] appends strings from an array using ng-click but does not employ ng-include so it can't compile my template. I've went through trying to combine the two with no success.

Comment: Can accomplish the `remove` with `ng-click` and no need to use jQuery or a directive  http://jsfiddle.net/M45G3/40/

Comment: right, the remove functionality was in the original second JSfiddle from my comment above. The trouble I'm having is getting that same add and remove functionality on a template because it needs to be ran through $compile or ng-include directive first(which does the $compile for you from what I've read).

Comment: I've got the add input by button click in the directives found in this JSFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/KyEr3/72/]. I already have another ng-click function on the counter decrement button that I want to use to remove the inputs. Can both actions be combined in the same ng-click? Or is there a way to create another type 'E' element directive that would work similar to the add input directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to write directives for both appending and removing input elements and attached those to their respective increment and decrement buttons on the counter.

Here is the markup for the buttons

```
    <section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <addinputsbutton></addinputsbutton>
    <removeinputsbutton></removeinputsbutton>
    <div id="space-for-inputs"></div>
    </section>
```

..and here are the directives.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;


}

//Directive that returns an element which adds inputs on click
myApp.directive("addinputsbutton", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<button id='{{$index}}' class=\"count-btn ion-arrow-up-b\" ng-click=\"increment()\" ng-init=\"count=0\" addinputs><span class=\"ion-plus-round\">+</span></button>"
    }
});

//Directive for adding inputs on click
myApp.directive("addinputs", function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("click", function(){

            angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-inputs')).append($compile("<div class='resource-input'><input id='{{$index}}' type=\"text\" name=\"resource{{$index}}\" required><label for=\"resource{{$index}}\">Enter a Name to Display</label></div>")(scope));
        });
    };
});

//_______________________________________________________________________  

 //Directive that returns an element which removes inputs on click
myApp.directive("removeinputsbutton", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<button id='{{$index}}' class=\"count-btn ion-arrow-down-b\" ng-click=\"decrement()\" ng-init=\"count=0\" removeinputs><span class=\"ion-minus-round\">-</span></button>"
    }
});

//Directive for removing inputs on click
myApp.directive('removeinputs', function(){
  return function(scope, element){
    element.bind('click', function(){

      document.getElementById('space-for-inputs').removeChild(document.getElementById('space-for-inputs').lastChild);

    });
  };
});
```

For some reason I couldn't get the 'addinput' and 'removeinput' directives to work in JSFiddle unless I added them to a custom button created from the element directives. But the 'addinput' and 'removeinput' elements worked fine in plain button tags in my application. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyEr3/91/)  in case any one is interested.